# Listview automatically changes width inside linearlayout

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-linearlayout

I was trying to implement a simple UI which shows a list of things. It has a top toolbar and a text area at bottom. 
I put everything into a LinearLayout. Toolbar has fixed height and bottom text area has variable height depending on text written. The rest of the screen is supposed to occupied by the list.
When I try to type something into the EditText element and it has more than one line, the listview starts showing random behaviour. 
All the elements in the list are on the right side of the screen initially. But they somehow come to the left side.

**How to prevent this behaviour?**

The code is given below:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#ff6e00"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/back_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:src="@mipmap/backbutton_transparent"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:clickable="true"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textSize="24dp"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/conversation_list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp">

    </ListView>
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#dfdfdf"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/writing_area"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:minHeight="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/written_text"
            android:hint="Enter message"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:maxLines="6"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"/> 
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

the getView of the adapter is

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent ) {
    Log.v(TAG,"getView: called");
    Item date = getItem(position);
    Log.v(TAG,"getView called with data");
       convertView = mInflator.inflate(R.layout.item, parent,false);
TextView view = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
    view.setText(message.getText());
    return convertView;
}
```

the item xml file is

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/orange_rounded_rectangle"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:maxWidth="240dp" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The behaviour doesn't have a pattern. It happens sometimes and doesn't happens other times when text area has multiple lines.

I tried various thing to solve it. 
I checked the layout lines for the view. It shows that somehow the listview width has changed. The list view boundry  has shrunk so list element are forced to be on left side even thought they are aligned to border of parent.

I checked logs also. they all get re-rendered by using correct list element xml file which is supposed to align them to right.

I tried using other layouts but cannot use scroll view as list is also scrollable.
I also tried constraint layout but it stops showing the text area. The list occupies all space below the toolbar as it has weight one and text area is supposed to have wrap_content height.

Comment: Try to add `configChanges=screenSize` attribute in manifest for desired activity. If this behavior appear on keyboard open the try to add attributes `android:configChanges="screenSize|keyboard`.

Comment: Could you add sample adapter ur using and the row view.

Comment: @Rockin added the adapter getView method and item xml file

Comment: @AkashGarg .Do you do something in the text change of your edittext?

Comment: nothing special. Its just supposed to wrap adjust size naturally and maxLines can go upto 6 after that it gets scroll bar. But that just natural. haven't setup anything special for it.

Comment: could you comment the code in edittext if any and check if the behaviour is same?

Comment: There is no listener for edittext. Its only in xml and has bare minimum things like width and height etc. set. I know it happens because the size can change when typing more text. But thats a requirement in the end.